# Column having 23 digits in databricks table gets saved as 'Exponential' as default in Excel. How to overcome?

Tags: sql, azure, databricks

I have a column in my table from a SQL query orderline ID which is more than 20 digits long. When I download the data to excel, it automatically saves it as 'Exponential' format. How can I overcome this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the number is more than 15 digits it is converted into a scientific notation in excel.

As an alternative, download the file in CSV/text and import the file in excel with text format.